# Android, работа с vk

Tags: android

Надо написать Android приложение, в котором можно будет входить в свой аккаунт ВК, получать новостную ленту, ставить лайки и надо это сделать без использования vk sdk, можете подсказать как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: Без использования Vk sdk - это Вам Api тоже не подходит?

Comment: Да, не подходит, задание состоит в том,чтобы получить данные именно без использования api

Comment: парсите тогда сайт, что тут еще предложить) Но это прям very bad решение